# How to hide an <option> in <select> with an if condition?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

So this is the working HTML for adjusting the zoom.

What I need to do now is how to hide the 200 option with an if condition using Javascript.

So if a variable is greater than the 200 option, I need to hide it.

EDIT:
I was wrong explaining it, so if a variable is greater than another variable, I need to hide the 200 option and display the 100, 300, and 400.

```
<div id="zoomAdjuster' class="centerAlign">
  <span>Zoom</span>
  <select name="chooseAZoom">
     <option value="100" selected>100</option>
     <option value="200">200</option>
     <option value="300">300</option>
     <option value="400">400</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

Please help, I don't know much about this language. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the `select` using any document query method and then select the options. Then iterate the options and check for the value. If value is grater than 200 then add a class to hide it

```js
const z = document.getElementsByName('chooseAZoom')[0].querySelectorAll('option').forEach((elem) => {
  if (elem.value >= 200) {
    elem.classList.add('hideOption')

  }

})
```

```css
.hideOption {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div id="zoomAdjuster" class="centerAlign">
  <span>Zoom</span>
  <select name="chooseAZoom">
    <option value="100" selected>100</option>
    <option value="200">200</option>
    <option value="300">300</option>
    <option value="400">400</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also remove the `option` tags from the DOM. By:

- Selecting the `select` tag from the DOM, then get its children `option` tags, put those in an array with the spread syntax.
- Filtering the array and remove the `option` tag with the `value` of 200, if your variable is larger than 200. Else keep the array.
- Clear all the `option` tags inside`select`, then loop through the filtered array and appending the option tags back to `select`

```js
let yourVariable = 201;

const select = document.querySelector('select[name=chooseAZoom]');
const optArr = [...select.children];

const newOptArr = optArr.filter(opt => {
  if (yourVariable > 200)
    return opt.value != 200;
  return true;
})

select.innerHTML = "";
newOptArr.forEach(opt => select.appendChild(opt));
```

```html
<div id="zoomAdjuster" class="centerAlign" >
      <span>Zoom</span>
      <select name="chooseAZoom">
       <option value="100" selected>100</option>
       <option value="200">200</option>
       <option value="300">300</option>
       <option value="400">400</option>
      </select>
</div>
```